# Reading a file to define which words are palindromes

Tags: python, file, reverse

Writing a program to display all the palindrome words from a text file. A palindrome word is a word that reads same backward as forward. How would I write this code?

```py
fileobj = ("data.txt", "r")   
file_data = fileobj.read()   

name = (data)   
reverse_name = ''.join(reversed(name))  
  
if name == reverse_name:    
    print("Palindrome")    
else:       
    print("Not")
```

Comment: What is `data`?

Comment: You're not splitting the file into words.

Comment: For starters, you need to open the file to read it: i.e. `fileobj = open("data.txt", "r")`.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the input text file (`text.txt`) is:

```
abc abba
xyx onyx
```

Then you can try:

```py
with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
            if word == word[::-1]:
                print(f"{word}: palindromic")
            else:
                print(f"{word}: not palindromic")

# abc: not palindromic
# abba: palindromic
# xyx: palindromic
# onyx: not palindromic
```

This uses `open ... as` to open a file, `for line in f` to loop over lines, `for word in line.split()` to loop over words in each line, and then `word == word[::-1]` to check whether the word is palindromic.